# Erro do pygame ao usar o key.get_pressed()

Tags: python, pygame

Estava testando o `pygame`, e me deparei com um erro. Fiz um quadrado vermelho aparecer na tela, e fiz o codigo para ele se mover também, configurei o WASD para a locomoção, mas quando execultei o codigo, e apertava as teclas configuradas (WASD) o quadrado não se movia. Então decidi mudar as teclas configuradas pelas setas, quando eu execultei o codigo, estava tudo normal o quadrado estava se movendo da meneira correta com as setas, mas não com o WASD.

> Meu codigo com o WASD

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
# Iniciando os pacotes do pygame
pygame.init() 
# tela onde passará o jogo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,500]) 

x = 200
y = 200

while True:
    # verificando todos os eventos do usuário
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit() # se o usuário apertar para sair, a janela fecha
        
    screen.fill([0,0,0])
            
   # quadrado vermelho que irá aparecer na tela
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x,y,40,40))

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_w]:
        y -= 20
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_s]:
        y += 20
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_a]:
        x -= 20
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_d]:
        x += 20
    
    # atualiza os frames do jogo
    pygame.display.update()
```

> meu codigo com as setas

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
# Iniciando os pacotes do pygame
pygame.init() 
# tela onde passará o jogo
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800,500]) 

x = 200
y = 200

while True:
    # verificando todos os eventos do usuário
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit() # se o usuário apertar para sair, a janela fecha
        
    screen.fill([0,0,0])
            
   # quadrado vermelho que irá aparecer na tela
    quadrado = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), (x,y,40,40))

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        y -= 20
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        y += 20
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        x -= 20
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        x += 20
    
    # atualiza os frames do jogo
    pygame.display.update()
```

Até o momento não tentei nada, pois não tenho ideia do que tentar. Agradeço.

Comment: Aqui funcionou normal com as teclas WASD

Comment: Estranho, pois tentei uma ultima vez, e ainda não esta funcionando.

Comment: Você tem alguma ideia do que pode ser, e como resolver?

Comment: Como está executado o código? Teve algum erro?

Comment: Não, apenas mostrou a versão do pygame e o link da comunidade.

Comment: E como executou?

Comment: Quando seguro alguma tecla (WASD) o quadrado anda um pouco e dá uma engasgada. Depois disso não se mexe mais. Já com as setas, o jogo fluiu normalmente.

Comment: E como executou?

Comment: Desculpe, mas não entendi sua pergunta.

Comment: Como você executou o código? Direto no terminal?

Comment: Exato, foi pelo terminal.

Comment: Oi, olhei nas minhas configurações, e resolvi o meu problema, me desculpe qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 0):

você precisa criar uma variavel com o pygame.key.get_pressed()

```
comandos = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if comandos[pygame.K_w]: ###key pode ser qualquer tecla como K_a K_1 etc
    y -= 20
```